# Что такое панталык?

Tags: этимология, фразеология

Сбить с толку — то же самое, что сбить с панталыку. А что такое этот самый панталык? Откуда пошло выражение?
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Сбиться с панталыку — такое выражение также известно в украинском и польском языках, в других славянских языках его нет. "Узбий Енея с пантелику" — в таком виде оборот впервые отмечен у Котляревского в 1798 году. В русских словарях обозначается с середины 19 века.

Вероятно, слово заимствовано из тюркских языков, об этом говорит характерная концовка ЫК. Возможно, исходное выражение "панд-лык" — хитрый прием. Кроме того, существует тюркское слово "панлык" — гордость, чванство.

Также следует учесть, что на русско-украинской почве на выражение "сбиться с панталыку" сказалось влияние слова "толк".

Comment: "Почтенье дорогому свату! 
                   Гей, пан Эол, ну как живешь? - 
                   Промолвила, влетая в хату, 
                   Юнона. - Не гостей ли ждешь?" 
                   Поставила тарелку с хлебом 
                   Перед Эолом - старым дедом, 
                   На лавку села у дверей. 
                   "Будь ласков, сватушка, как другу, 
                   Мне нынче окажи услугу - 
                   Энея с панталыку сбей.

Comment: >"Узбий Елея с пантелику" - в таком виде оборот впервые отмечен у Котляревского в 1798 году.
ЭНея. Это "Энеида", шуточное переложение Котляревским "Энеиды" Вергилия.

"Iзбий Енея з пантелику"

Answer (score 7):

Академик Трубачев в примечании к словарной статье Фасмера "панталык" говорит следущее :

> в слове панталык вместе с укр. диал., карп. пантлик, пантлика "лента", польск. диал. petlik, petlika "петля, завязка", слвц. pantlik, мор. pentlik можно видеть заимствование из австрийско-бав. раntl "завязка, ленточка", откуда и венг. pantlika...

В продолжение данного мнения академика приведу следующий текст :

> Панталык
>
> На юге России часто говорят сбить с панталыку, то есть «сбить с толку». Что такое панталык?
>
> Сейчас это выражение действительно означает «сбить с толку, поставить в тупик, отвлечь от логической цепочки мыслей». Но когда-то оно имело несколько иной смысл – «обескуражить, сбить с куража».
>
> Слово панталык занесено в южные диалекты от карпатских гуцулов, которые вовсю пользуются заимствованиями из венгерского и немецкого языков. Австрийцы словом pantl называют петли и разнообразные завязки. Венгерское pantlika значит «ленточка, завязка». В словацком языке есть слово p'antlik, обозначающее цветные ленты и завязанные из них банты, украшающие одежду.
>
> Представьте, нашили вы на себя все эти ленточки, навесили бантики, как на рождественскую елку, вышли погулять этаким франтом, а кто-то словом или делом взял да и сбил с вас все ваше чванство. Вот это и есть буквально сбить с панталыку.

[Ссылка](http://www.e-reading.ws/chapter.php/129629/204/Hrappa_-_Ot_adamova_yabloka_do_yabloka_razdora._Proishozhdenie_slov_i_vyrazheniii.html)